# What is our stance on questions asking about MOOCs?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions asking about MOOCs? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

To put it otherwise, are MOOCs regarded as part of academia by this Stack Exchange community? (or do you prefer to wait a few years before?)

Comment: Also see [Studying by MOOC on-topic or off?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/789/studying-by-mooc-on-topic-or-off)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the question is about. Questions asking about pedagogy, organization, and similar matters that aren't course-specific are fine. Questions that are too closely tied to a given course are probably not, as would be questions that are platform-specific. ("How do I enable feature X in course Y?" is probably not appropriate.)

Comment: FYI see comments on [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72691/for-profit-mooc-platforms-vs-non-profit-mooc-platforms-what-difference-does-it) for context.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, MOOCs are services that are sometimes used in academia and sometimes used in a totally non-academic context (e.g. for self study for fun, for training in the workplace.)

I consider questions that are directly relevant to those using MOOCs in higher education to be on topic. I **don't** consider questions about MOOCs outside the context of academia or academic people to be on topic.

This seems consistent with the community history here. For example, [is it possible to master one topic by starting with a MOOC course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/is-it-possible-to-master-one-topic-by-starting-with-a-mooc-course) was closed by the community for this reason.

Comment: I disagree that your view seems consistent with the community history. E.g.,  [How are instructors compensated for teaching a Massive Open Online Course (MOOC)?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11405/452) was well received. (and it is about payment to the MOOC instructors, who are not necessarily affiliated with an university.) The question you linked to had [other issues](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/789/452).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Clearly you are defining "within the context of academia" much more narrowly than me. The [vast majority](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01587919.2015.1081736) of MOOC instructors work at a college or university, and the content of that question indicates as much ("does teaching these come with compensation of any kind? Salary/bonus? Teaching load reduction? Release from service? Teaching assistants for the courses? I'm interested in compensation either from one's university or from the MOOC provider")

Comment: The study focused on Coursera and edX websites, which I think contains more academics than some other places. That being said, in my opinion, MOOCs are pretty much some online media to teach, and, I agree with you, often involving traditional, physical universities, so questions about MOOCs should be on-topic (aside from the issues that aeismail pointed out, which also apply to traditional universities). As a side note, I have always found pay-walled studies about MOOCs to quite quite ironical :/